# Dynamic Text from a selection

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, dynamic-text

In my layout view in ArcGIS Pro (2.9), I want to add a title that displays the currently selected parcel in the map frame.  I have looked through the dynamic text tags and the table attribute option is close, but I need to limit it to just the selected parcels.  Is there an expression I can use that would only use the attribute data for the selected parcels?

Comment: Is the map part of a map series? So you going to churn out dozens of maps? If it is just one map, then quicker to do it manually.

Comment: No it's not a map series, but it's a process my editors use regularly.  Before beginning an edit process, they create a before map to include in the documentation.  So I have a layout template set up for them and the last piece would be for it to automatically title the map based on the selected parcel.

Comment: If all the maps are about the same set of parcels, then Hornbydd's suggestion of a map series still might make sense.  Each parcel would be a page in a map series, when they choose a parcel they would go to the map page for that parcel and export a single map of it, not the whole series.  The map series setup allows you to use auto fills and selection symbologies and even different inserts even if you only produce one map at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you are asking is not possible as I believe the current release of Arcade does not honour selections. Also the Layout profile of Arcade seems to only accept $feature global.

There is a work around but it requires a little bit of effort by you:

1. Add a text field of 1 character length, call it *selected*.
2. Select your parcels
3. Run a field calculate on your text field *selected* and set it to **Y**.
4. Switch selection
5. Re-run the field calculate on the text field *selected* and set the rows to **N**.

In your layout add the table attribute dynamic text and set it up as below:

Field drop-down is the parcel name/ID/some bit of text. This is being filtered by rows where selected = 'Y'.

[image: Table Attribute]

An advantage of this approach is that you can list the select parcel names in your title because you are filtering by an SQL query so you can actually clear the selection on the layer.